# how to set repeat week days in android alarm

Tags: android, alarm

i am making an alarm app. in this app i am getting problem to set week days. here i am using a dialog box with check boxes. when i select one box than it is setting but if i select two or multiple boxes than it is overriding all and setting last checked box means it is setting only one time alarm.

my code is here and please show me any way what i do...

```
   final String days[]={"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"};
AlertDialog.Builder weekDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(SetAlarm.this);
weekDialog.setTitle("Select repeat days");
weekDialog.setMultiChoiceItems(days, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int pos, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

});
weekDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SparseBooleanArray CheCked = ((AlertDialog) arg0).getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();

        if (CheCked.get(0))
        {
            forday(2);
        }
        if (CheCked.get(1))
        {
            forday(3);
        }
        if (CheCked.get(2))
        {
            forday(4);
        }
        if (CheCked.get(3))
        {
            forday(5);
        }
        if (CheCked.get(4))
        {
            forday(6);
        }
        if (CheCked.get(5))
        {
            forday(7);
        }
        if (CheCked.get(6))
        {
            forday(1);
        }
        Toast.makeText(SetAlarm.this, "week day has been selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

 weekDialog.show();
 }
 private void forday(int week) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, week);
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

if (c.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
c.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```